# SQL Query to Fetch Revenue Per Month and Cost Per Sale For Each SKU in The Database

Tags: sql, shopify

I have a Shopify table that I need to fetch the Revenue Per Month and Cost Per Sale For Each SKU in The Database. Does anyone here know how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What platform are you using to query this data? Does this have to be done in Shopify's `Liquid` script?

Comment: No it does not have to be Liquid. I can export the database and use any platform

Comment: If you can export it,then please determine the platform you will use and tag that in the question so that we can answer it. The solution will quite different between Excel, an RDBMS, Awk or where ever else you might do such a thing. For example, in Excel I would just toss a pivot table around the data to get both of these numbers, but in MySQL I would write something like `SELECT monthField, sum(Revenue) FROM  myTable GROUP BY monthField;` to get the first number.

Comment: My preferred platform will be [tag:MySQL] but I think [tag:Excel] would work too. Thank you @JNevil